# MySQL connection doesn't work from Kubernetes pod because of SSL

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, kubernetes, openssl

I am running Kubernetes on my Windows host and want to execute a Python script where I connect to a MySQL database outside the cluster.
When I execute the script from my Windows host, it works finde, but inside the cluster, it says:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'x.x.x.x:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Do you know how to solve this?
My OpenSSL version is the same on my host and in the cluster:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
built on: ...
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc ...
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with **ssl_verify_cert** to **False** when connecting to **MySQL** from Python.